# How to read response JSON as structs when they contain hyphens in key names?

Tags: json, rust, json-deserialization, serde, reqwest

I am querying an API for some data but their keys have hyphens instead of underscores in their names, and since I can't have hyphens in struct field names, I am unable to cast it.

For example, my struct:

```
pub struct Example {
    user_id: String,
    name: String,
}
```

and the received json is like

```
{
    "user-id": "abc",
    "name": "John"
}
```

Right now i'm doing this but i can't because i can't directly cast it

```
let res = client
    .get("SOME-URL")
    .header("x-api-key", APP_ID)
    .send()
    .await?;

let response_body: Example = res.json().await?;
```

Comment: Are you using serde? If so, you have a couple options: (1) use [`#[serde(rename_all = "kebab-case")]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#rename_all) at the struct level, (2) use [`#[serde(rename = "user-id")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#rename) at the field level.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I will do, I am using serde

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is just a single attribute, you can use:

- [`#[serde(alias = "user-id")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#alias)
- [`#[serde(rename = "user-id")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#rename)

If it is all of them (kebab case, or other styling) you can use:

[`#[serde(rename_all = "kebab-case")]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#rename_all)

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Example {
    #[serde(alias = "user-id")]
    user_id: String,
    name: String,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=786cfa5115dcdecb25a2372acaf73e7f)

Comment: Yes, it's just a couple attributes, I am going to try this.